# Why is the following operator independent of the choice of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a lie group with lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and let $M$ be a $G$-manifold. We denote the space of smooth differential forms on $M$ by $A(M)$. Let $E^i$ be a basis of $\mathfrak{g}$ and let $E_i$ $\in \mathfrak{g}^*$ be the dual basis. Let $S(\mathfrak{g}^*)$ be the symmetric algebra of $\mathfrak{g}^*$. Define the operator $\overline{d}$ on $S(\mathfrak{g}^*) \otimes A(M)$ by

$$\overline{d}(P \otimes \alpha)= \sum_i E_iP \otimes \iota (E^i_M) \alpha$$

for $P \in S(\mathfrak{g}^*)$ and $\alpha \in A(M)$ (note that $\iota (E^i_M)$ is the contraction by the vector field $E^i_M$ wich is defined by $$(E^i_M.f)(m)= \frac{d}{dt} \bigg|_{t=0} f(\exp(tE^i)m),$$ for $f \in C^\infty(M)$ and $m \in M$).

My question is why  the definition of $\overline{d}$ is independent of the choice of the basis $E^i$ ?

Actually, I get this question by reading section $2$ of the article of equivariant cohomology with generalized coefficients by Kumar and Vergne, and the authors have commented on this by saying the following

> This expression is independent of the choice of the basis $E^i$, as the element $\sum_i E_i \otimes E^i \in \mathfrak{g}^* \otimes \mathfrak{g}$ is the canonical element $I \in \operatorname{End}(\mathfrak{g})$, where $I$ is the identity element of $\operatorname{End}(\mathfrak{g})$.

But I didn't understand their comment! Moreover, I tried to prove this independence in the case where $\mathfrak{g}$ is one dimensional without going any where.

Please help with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $k$, there is a canonical isomorphism of vector spaces $\varphi : V \otimes V^* \to \operatorname{End}_k(V)$, such that $v \otimes f$ gets taken to the linear operator $\varphi(v \otimes f): u \mapsto v f(u)$ and extended linearly. This map is not hard to understand in terms of a basis: if $e_1, \ldots, e_n$ is a basis of $V$ and $e_1^*, \ldots, e_n^*$ the dual basis, and we identify $\operatorname{End}_k(V)$ with $n \times n$ matrices using this basis, then $\varphi(e_i \otimes e_j^*)$ is the matrix with a $1$ in the $(i, j)$ place and zeros elsewhere.

Inside the vector space $\operatorname{End}_k(V)$ we have the identity map $\operatorname{id}_V \colon V \to V$, and we can ask what it corresponds to in $V \otimes V^*$. Many authors call this the *canonical element* $\varphi^{-1}(\operatorname{id}_V) \in V \otimes V^*$. Once we fix a basis and its dual, it is easy to check that $\varphi^{-1}(\operatorname{id}_V) = \sum_i e_i \otimes e_i^*$. Moreover, since $\varphi^{-1}(\operatorname{id}_V)$ was defined independent of any basis, it must be true for *every* basis and its dual that $\varphi^{-1}(\operatorname{id}_V) = \sum_i e_i \otimes e_i^*$.

Comment: thank you so much@Joppy for your helpful answer.

Comment: Hi! I understand the answer, but I don't know how to use it to answer the  question : why is the operator d independent of the choice of the basis? Could any  one explain this please ?